# Black borders around images imported as empty

Tags: import, image

[image]
Attached here's the screenshot you can see outside the sneaker (Shoe) object there is border its an png i have crossed checked again there is no border no outline outside the png image
How to get rid off black border.. I have imported the image in blender as an empty image.  I want to animate the sneaker (shoe) on opacity.  If I imported the sneaker image as an planes then opacity option is not there - which i can't animate
Also if one can guide me on camera animation would be great or provide the link for the same.

Comment: Isn't that just a visual indicator of size of the image inside the viewport? It will not be visible in a render. Just hit F12 and see if it's there.

Comment: Thanks tried both the options render > render image F12 - the shoe sneaker is not visible. (image is imported as empty  > add > empty > Image. as i need to animate the opacity of the shoe sneaker image )  But in  object mode > view > viewport render image, the shoe sneaker image is visible but with black borders.  In the final out put render animation black border is visible .